# How to individual update checkbox in antd checkbox group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[I have created](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-johnson-y7rft) a [`Checkbox.Group`](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/#Checkbox-Group) using ant design, based on the values from API, the following checkboxes should get checked.

```js
const options = [
  { label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' },
  { label: 'Pear', value: 'Pear' },
  { label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' }
];

const valuesFromApi = ['Apple', 'Pear'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Checkbox.Group
      options={options}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={valuesFromApi}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[image: Edit aged-cdn-u6jf2]

Comment: Can you show the code related to this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify `value` property for [`Checkbox-Group`](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/#Checkbox-Group)

> **value** -   Used for setting the currently selected value.

```js
const options = [
  { label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' },
  { label: 'Pear', value: 'Pear' },
  { label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' }
];

const valuesFromApi = ['Apple', 'Pear'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Checkbox.Group
      options={options}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={valuesFromApi}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a working example for you.

What it does is give you the ability to store the checked values from the CheckBox Group and store them in the state for possible future use.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-austin-olp1x).

Please let me know if something is not clear enough.

**PS:** I have used [destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for defining variables.

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089573/how-to-checked-multiple-checkbox-in-react-js